# TextStyle not applied to ListView itemBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter/dart and running through the tutorial. I'm trying to set the text style of a `ListView` but it's not being applied.

```
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final _font = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.blueAccent);

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return Divider();
        final index = i ~/ 2;
        if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
        }
        return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
      }
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair w) {
    print(_font);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        WordPair.random().asPascalCase,
        style: _font)
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildSuggestions();
  }

}
```

It works if I create a new `TextStyle` directly within the Text Widget, but doesn't when I supply a final ivar provided by the State class itself and I wonder why?

So this works:

```
  Widget _buildRow(WordPair w) {
    print(_font);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        WordPair.random().asPascalCase,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.blueAccent))
      );
  }
```

But this doesn't:

```
  Widget _buildRow(WordPair w) {
    print(_font);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        WordPair.random().asPascalCase,
        style: _font)
      );
  }
```

Comment: It seem to have been just an issue with hot reload. Changing the TextStyle didn't update the view, however restarting the app did. Still strange though why it's not picking up the change? I'm using VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because hot reload recalls your build function in the state class again, but the class is not reloaded again, so it doesn't pick any changes outside of your build function. Do a full reload in order to do it.